# Paint not showing up

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am using a JFrame and a pane and trying to draw a simple square.
My painting is not showing up. I made I set the color to black so it should be visible.
Code:

```
    package W2;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import javax.swing.*;       

    public class W2 {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("W2");

        public W2(){                
            Container pane = new Container();
            frame.setContentPane(pane);
            frame.setSize(750,500);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            new W2();
        }

    }
```

Comment: That paint method is just something you created in the W2. Nothing related with painting in Swing. Please take a look at the Swing tutorials and start over. You need to override `paintComponent` you are not doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `paint` method won't be called because it's not part of a object that can be painted.

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for details about how painting is done in Swing

For example...

```
frame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
});
```